# Create battery widget for Android in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-widget

I want to create a battery widget for android in phonegap.Is this possible with phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

I think no support of android widgets in PhoneGap according to [this post on google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/53982bfabcf66a74/37c708b0e8b5849f?lnk=gst&q=android+widget#37c708b0e8b5849f)

Comment: battery events were added in the 1.2.0 release after the 2010 post you reference

Answer (score 0):

See the battery methods in the [events API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html).